# Create WP Query to get the child pages of all hierarchy levels with meta_query

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm worried that I can't write correct WP Query to get the child pages of all hierarchy levels with meta_query.

So this is what I have now

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'page',
    'post_parent'       => get_the_ID(),
    'meta_key'          => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value'        => 'singletour.php',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
)

$q = new WP_Query($args);
```

So I can get only first level of child pages with this args. How to get child pages of all hierarchy levels with 'singletour.php' template?